# Share scale factor between Text views

Tags: ios, swiftui

I'm trying to implement Calendar YearView which consists of MonthViews and so far the result is good:

[image: Calendar monospaced font]

However, in order to achieve this result I had to use a monospaced font (for weekday labels and day labels) which has different look and feel from the regular one. Just compare what happens if I change the font to the regular one:

[image: Calendar regular font]

The problem with non-monospaced font is that Text views for day labels are getting different scale factors since I use `.lineLimit(1).minimumScaleFactor(0.001)`.

Here is a simple demo to play and see the effect in action:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var w: CGFloat = 200
    @State var h: CGFloat = 200
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            VStack {
                HStack {
                    Group {
                        Text("1")
                        Text("30")
                    }
                    .border(.red)
                    .lineLimit(1)
                    .minimumScaleFactor(0.001)
                    .font(.headline)
                    .scaledToFill()
                }
                HStack {
                    Group {
                        Text("9")
                        Text("11")
                    }
                    .border(.red)
                    .lineLimit(1)
                    .minimumScaleFactor(0.001)
                    .font(.headline)
                    .scaledToFill()
                }
            }
            .scaledToFit()
            .padding()
            .frame(width: w, height: h)
            .border(.blue)
            
            Spacer()
            Slider(value: $w, in: 1...500)
            Slider(value: $h, in: 1...300)
        }
    }
}
```

While dragging two sliders at the bottom it becomes obvious that numbers get different scale factor.

**Question:** How do I share the common scale factor between text views which are placed in a "grid" layout and not using monospaced fonts like we see in Calendars? Any other approaches like manually calculating font sizes in advance using GeometryReader are welcome :)

Comment: IMO it is not appropriate to use here, instead calculate regular cell w/h and then fit number into it, thus all numbers will be equal.

Comment: @Asperi Calculating cell w/h would require to think of so many details like spacing between cells, spacing between month views, paddings and so on. Am I wrong? And then I would have to calculate a font size for the given cell w/h...

Answer (score 1):

You should not allow text to scale on their behalf. If you provide width space and fixed height for them, all of them will take the same scaling.

for example, you can use a simple grid to build the entire month view like:

```
struct MonthView: View {
    let data = (1...30).map(String.init)
    let columns = Array(repeating: GridItem(.flexible()), count: 7)
    
    var body: some View {
        LazyVGrid(columns: columns, alignment: .leading, spacing: 8) {
            ForEach(data, id: \.self, content: Text.init)
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

[image: Demo]

<sub>There are more APIs to make view sizes more relative but you may need higher iOS versions (like 16) to support them or implement them yourself</sub>

Comment: if I place 3 instances of your MonthView in a row (HStack), then run it on simulator iPhone 12: there will be all kind of artifcats like text is shifted to arbitrary places making the whole thing unreadable :( When 3 instances are used in a row text should be downscaled in some way... In your example I don't see how it can get to be downscaled.

Comment: You can achieve what you want by playing with the properties **[like this example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3MGx7.png)**

Comment: Which properties do you mean specifically? Did you get your screenshot from iPhone/iOS, because there the screen width is not enough to squeeze 3 instances on MonthView without downscaling fonts?